# Unexpected return type when a Func is used in Join query projection

Tags: c#, linq, delegates

I have a join query and I want to project one of the objects being joined with some minor changes in it. I figured out that the best way to do this would be to project a `Func` that makes the changes that I need.

Of the two lists that I am joining, one is a `List<dynamic>` and the other is `List<ReceiptBE>`.

My `Func` is supposed to return a `ReceiptBE`, but in the join projection when I call the `Func`, the result of the join query is of type `IEnumerable<dynamic>`. However, when I convert the same `Func` to an Inline method, the result of the same join query is of type `IEnumerable<ReceiptBE>`.

Func Implementation:

```
public void Method1()
{
        Func<ReceiptBE, dynamic, ReceiptBE> myFunc = (receipt, link) =>
        {
                receipt.something = link.something.ToString();
                return receipt;
        };

        var receiptDetails = new List<ReceiptBE>();
        var receiptLinks = new List<dynamic>(); 

        //result is IEnumerable<dynamic>
        //why is result not IEnumerable<ReceiptBE> ?
        var result = from receiptLink in receiptLinks
                                join receiptDetail in receiptDetails on receiptLink.something.ToString() equals receiptDetail.something
                                select myFunc(receiptDetail, receiptLink);

        //result2 is IEnumerable<ReceiptBE>
        var result2 = from receiptLink in receiptLinks
                                join receiptDetail in receiptDetails on receiptLink.something.ToString() equals receiptDetail.something
                                select myFunc(receiptDetail, receiptLink) as ReceiptBE;

}
```

Local method implementation:

```
public void Method2()
{
        ReceiptBE myInlineMethod(ReceiptBE receipt, dynamic link)
        {
                receipt.something = link.something.ToString();
                return receipt;
        }

        var receiptDetails = new List<ReceiptBE>();
        var receiptLinks = new List<dynamic>(); 

        //result is IEnumerable<ReceiptBE>
        var result = from receiptLink in receiptLinks
                                join receiptDetail in receiptDetails on receiptLink.something.ToString() equals receiptDetail.something
                                select myInlineMethod(receiptDetail, receiptLink);
}
```

Also, when I write `myInlineMethod` as a private class method, again the type of result becomes `IEnumerable<dynamic>`

What I want in the `result` is `IEnumerable<ReceiptBE>` and because local method is a c# 7 feature (few people in organization use VS2015), I am stuck with the `Func` implementation with a cast.

Please guide me to the docs where I can read about this behavior of `Func`.

Comment: Hello! What is your actual question?:)

Comment: This is interesting point. When defining lambda-expression explicitly the result won't be dynamic:
*var result3 = (from receiptLink in receiptLinks join receiptDetail in receiptDetails on receiptLink.something.ToString() equals receiptDetail.something select new { rd=receiptDetail, rl=receiptLink })
.Select(a => { a.rd.something = a.rl.something.ToString(); return a.rd; })
.ToArray();*

Comment: @vladimir I would rather just cast the `Func` result as `ReceiptBE` than do an additional select.